# Компиляция Си файла через командную строку

Tags: c, компиляция, командная-строка

Как можно через команды в командной строке скомпилировать .c файл с помощью gcc? В принципе это не столь принципиально, у меня sumblime 3 + MinGW настроены и всё работает, но хочется научиться это делать вручную в командной строке.

Comment: В простейшем случае `gcc имя_файла.c`

Comment: Выводится ошибка. Я так предполагаю, что файл должен быть расположен в какой-то конкретной директории. Но в какой? У меня файл находится в папке на рабочем столе

Comment: Какая ошибка выводится?

Comment: Сначала нужно в консоли выбрать рабочий стол как текущую папку, через `cd`. Обычно консоль открывается в `C:\Users\Имя`, так что достаточно сделать `cd Desktop`, чтобы попасть в `C:\Users\Имя\Desktop`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а как это можно сделать?

Comment: Отредактировал комментарий.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat поменял директорию, теперь ошибка не выводится, но файл и не компилируется

Comment: А что выводится? Ничего?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, ничего не выводится, лишь происходит автоматический перенос на новую строку и только.

Comment: Уверены, что не скомпилировалось? У меня все работает, создается `a.exe`. Попробуйте после компиляции написать в консоли `a`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, теперь всё получилось. А что значит эта команда 'а'?

Comment: Это имя экзешника. Можно писать `a` или `a.exe`, оба варианта запускают ваш файл. Кстати, вам надо бы с терминами разобраться. "Компиляция" - это, грубо говоря, создание .exe. Его запуск в компиляцию не входит.